# Sharepoint site privacy settings though code

Tags: sharepoint, privacy, pnp-js

I have stressed all morning regarding this minor issue.

I have x sharepoint sites, some of them are public some of them are private.
I want to be able to modify the privacy settings through code, but so far I have only been able to do it manually.

I can set the field if I create the site anew, but I have not managed to do it if the site already exists.

I have also looked into: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/?view=sharepoint-ps, but have not found a commandlet to update this.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/STxfz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLOGF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
I finally managed to get this to work using the
_api/SP.Directory.DirectorySession/Group(id) endpoint.

I could not find official documentation though, and had to do it by moniting the network traffic